# Does being a "protected veteran" have any perks?

Tags: united-states, human-resources

HR sent out a company-wide email asking everyone to provide their veteran status (not a veteran, veteran, protected veteran).  There are very few protected veterans / veterans in our company.  What if anything could this status mean for them, officially and unofficially?

Comment: You should ask HR. This is likely specific to your State / company

Comment: It's mostly for statistical and tax (company's benefit) purpose because you voluntarily give the information. They can say they employ X number of veterans and "proud" of it.

Comment: The question of what this means *at your company* is impossible for us to answer and off topic. However, if you are instead interested in what this status means for employees in the general sense, that might make for a good on-topic question that would be more easily answered.

Comment: Well, presumably you are "protected" from something; isn't that a benefit?

Comment: Your company gets tax breaks for having veterans employed.

Answer (score 3):

> What if anything could this status mean for them, officially and
>   unofficially?

It could mean anything. It may mean nothing.

In the last company where I worked, the company president (who was a veteran) took all the other veterans out to lunch on Veteran's Day each year. I don't recall anything different being done for those with protected veteran status.

Protected Veterans have some perks during the hiring process. Some employers are required to take affirmative action to recruit and hire protected veterans. see: https://adata.org/factsheet/VEVRAA

Most likely, your employer needs to report the numbers of protected veterans they have hired.

But if you really want to know, ask HR.

Comment: In all cases I've seen you'll need to get an Veteran ID card from the VA to prove your status. Otherwise all employers allow you to voluntarily give the status but it's mostly for statistical purpose. Otherwise anyone can say they are a veteran and unless they have their DD214 on file, no one can really prove otherwise.